# WCF service net.tcp binding security

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have wcf service hosted in IIS on remote server with Net.Tcp binding. I also have C# application that using this service. C# application and Service are connected over internet, not over local network. I want that only my app can using this service. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it really depends on how you want to implement security, if you want to use a SQL Server membership provider or a custom one, all depends on your needs and how you want to create/manage/store permissions, have a look at this article and ask more specific questions if you still have any:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647034.aspx

Davide.